# How to escape percent in a LIKE expression in qgis?

Tags: qgis, expression, escaping

How can we escape a percent character in a `LIKE` expression in QGIS?

For example, if I have the following column:

`123% , 15% , albert, greg, 15%`

How do I select all the values with `%` in it without changing the field?

It seems possible to do this in ArcGIS, according to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187316/selection-by-attribute-string-in-arcgis-10-with-wildcard-as-part-of-the-name/187323#187323) but I have not found an equivalent solution with QGIS.

I have tried escaping with `%%`, `\%`, `\\\%`, `[%]`, `^%`, etc. but without success.

---

[EDIT]

I actually truly was wondering if it is possible to escape the % (and _) character, rather than to use perfectly (valid) work-around. The example provided was but for illustration.
Any ideas?

Comment: i tried the solution mentioned here ; http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/87888/25139 and qgis created the following query "FIELDNAME" ILIKE '%%%' but it doesn't do the trick. Could it be a bug ?

Comment: As per your edit - agreed, really you need an answer to using a standard escape instead of workaround. If no answer appears here, worth filing a bug report!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a missing piece in QGIS in the past. But as of (upcoming) QGIS 2.14.8 and 2.18, `\` [has been introduced as escape char for `LIKE` and friends](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3535).

Just have a look at the builtin documentation for `LIKE` which ships with examples for the usage.

---

It is already possible to get these versions as pre-release versions (qgis-dev / qgis-rel-dev on OSGeo4W). As such, it is recommended to install them and test them so the developers can get an early feedback in case of problems.

---

For an approach compatible with earlier versions of QGIS, have a look at the [very inventive answer by gisnside](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213522/9839).

Comment: Thanks Matthias ! I admit this one had me occupied this morning : I looked for any SQL tricks, like with the ESCAPE keyword (https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php), I also checked replacing with %% or [%] et / or \ but it didn't work either. I was very surprised not to see a build-in solution, so I found one :) Happy to see someone has corrected that in any case.

Answer (score 5):

You can virtually replace your % in the value coming from the source field with another ascii sign or any string value, it will allow you to select the replacing percentage value with the following code :

```
replace( "FIELDNAME",'%','€' )  LIKE '%€'
```

This way, you don't have to modify your source values.

You could of course choose a unique value to make sure you don't select anything else, it would also work to select % values :

```
replace( "FIELDNAME",'%','_mytailorisrich' ) LIKE '%_mytailorisrich'
```

Comment: It works great!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
 right("FIELDNAME", 1) = '%'
```

or

```
 right("FIELDNAME", 1) like '%'
```

Just trying as I don't have values like yours - but it validates with QGIS...

Comment: First one works, although '1' is sufficient instead of '2'. There is no space or commas in the values. The second one does not work since the % is used as a wild card (hence the issue) and it therefore selects all.